# Multiple console applications updating same sql table using EF objectcontext

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, objectcontext

I have multiple console applications but they would be reading and inserting updating same sql table. I used transactionscope but I am getting this error
"Transaction (Process ID) was deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction."

I get an exception in my catch block. How can I avoid this?
I know what the problem is but I am not sure what should be the possible solution. I see a lot questions being asked on different forums but none of them really helped me.

Is everything good in my code?

```
bool isMaster = false;
tourneyInstanceTrackerId = 0;
using (JG_RummyEntities dbContext = new JG_RummyEntities())
{
try
{
using (TransactionScope transaction = new    TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required,new TransactionOptions { IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.RepeatableRead }))
                {
bool isAnyMaster = dbContext.TourneyInstanceTrackers.Any(t => t.IsMaster & t.TournamentId == tournamentId);
TourneyInstanceTracker tourneyInstanceTracker = new TourneyInstanceTracker
                    {
                        TournamentId = tournamentId,
                        IsMaster = !isAnyMaster,
                        CreateDate = DateTime.Now
                    };
                       dbContext.AddToTourneyInstanceTrackers(tourneyInstanceTracker);
dbContext.SaveChanges();
                    var result = dbContext.TourneyInstanceTrackers.Where(t => t.TournamentId == tournamentId)
                            .OrderByDescending(t => t.CreateDate)
                            .Select(t => new { t.IsMaster, t.Id })
                            .FirstOrDefault();
                    if (result != null)
                    {
                        isMaster = result.IsMaster;
                        tourneyInstanceTrackerId = result.Id;
                    }
                    transaction.Complete();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Logger.Log("Got exception in SetTournamentInTourneyInstanceTracker : " + ex.Message + ", " + ex.StackTrace + ", "+ tournamentId);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

`IsolationLevel.RepeatableRead` acts like a [`ReaderWriterLockSlim`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim(v=vs.110).aspx), many threads can read a record at the same time but as soon as one wants to write you must wait for all readers to finish then take a exclusive lock on the object till you finish writing.

So imagine you have a program, it reads object "A" waits a bit then writes object "A". Now lets look at what happens when two copies of the program runs.

```
Program 1     Program 2
---------     ---------
Begin Trans   Not Started
Read A        Begin Trans
Wait          Read A
Try Write A   Wait
Try Write A   Try Write A
Try Write A   Try Write A
Try Write A   Try Write A
```

You can see Program 1 is waiting for Program 2 to release its read lock, however Program 2 can't release its read lock until Program 1 releases its read lock. This situation where the two are waiting for the other to finish is called a **deadlock**.

The are two ways you get around this, one you could use the more restrictive `IsolationLevel.Serializable`, this blocks other readers until the transaction finishes.

```
Program 1     Program 2
---------     ---------
Begin Trans   Not Started
Read A        Begin Trans
Wait          Try Read A
Write A       Try Read A
End Trans     Read A
              Wait
              Write A
              End Trans
```

The other is you follow the exception's advice, on the block of code that caught the exception you re-run the function again until it gets through without another copy of the program blocking it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I changed IsolationLevel to Serializable but this also is of no help. This is the error I am getting, An error occurred while reading from the store provider's data reader. See the inner exception for details.,  at System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper`1.StoreRead(). This indeed is same error as I checked on internet. Just FYI My SQL table has only 4 columns one is Id which is primary key with IDENTITY(1,1) and other three are of bigint type.

Comment: You need to look at the inner exception to find the cause of the error.

Comment: As I was saying it was the same error.System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904). Transaction (Process ID 293) was deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction.

Comment: Does other code besides the code you have showin in your answer use `dbContext.TourneyInstanceTrackers`?